# How to load test a rest-ful web service through JMeter or any other tool?

Tags: web-services, rest, jmeter

I have a web service : http://test.hs.com/rest/service/checkUpdate

It takes input : Device MAC Address e.g. 48:02:2a:ed:02:63

Its output :

1 - Device not registered (If Device is not registered)

2 – This code (though I don't know what's this)

```
<ResourceSettings>
   <accessKey>AKIAI6CZBIRDKHMMN3QA</accessKey>
   <secretKey>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</secretKey>
   <endPoint>s3.amazonaws.com</endPoint>
   <mainBucketPath>healthslate-testing</mainBucketPath>
   <clinicBucketPath>dhjasdhasd</clinicBucketPath>
   <isUpdateAvailable>true</ isUpdateAvailable>
   <allowedBuild>2.3</allowedBuild>
</ResourceSettings>
```

How can I test the load on this web service through JMeter? I have no idea how to handle input/output of web services in JMeters? I need step-by-step guide regarding this. Please note that the developer of this web service says it is a rest-ful web service. How can I test a rest-ful web service by giving it input as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic approach in testing web services using jMemeter I would describe in some steps:

1. create webService project
2. deploy it on server
3. create Thread group
4. ADD SAMPLER-SOAP/XML -RPC REQUEST /or Http request for REST
5. add listener (e.g Results Tree)
6. run the test plan
7. view output

One can get more details at  [Webservice Test Plan](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_webservice_test_plan.htm) if you testing SOAP  or at [Using JMeter to test a RESTful web service](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfNn9OuuEyU) if you testing REST.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks so much..
Can you answer me on this as well? http://serverfault.com/questions/546027/continuous-hits-to-the-server-with-jmeter

Comment: @eugene.polschikov: Please suggest me where can I find step 4 data for RESTful web service? (`SOAP/XML-RPC Request` data). Thanks

Comment: @sarwar026, in jmeter samplers hierarchy it is actually located here: http://gyazo.com/d9f0d262c510addcbf232d593665fdcc    ;
all the needed plugins for jMeter with step by step setUp info you can get here: http://jmeter-plugins.org/    - http://gyazo.com/a6017ebb543bffc3eeb9fe007fbfa7ee

Hope this works fine for you :)

Comment: @eugene.polschikov I have a scenario, I need to send 10,000 different encrypted xml at the same time to a web service and when each of the response comes back, they should be decrypted on getting to jmeter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tutorials to get you started with JMeter: http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/topics/10018-jmeter-tutorials. You will need more information before you start testing

Answer (score 1):

[check out here for jmeter restful webservice tutorial here](http://www.jmeter.info/jmeter-tutorials/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer for people who are looking for some detailed steps to test a REST API using JMeter.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/how-to-test-rest-api-using-jmeter/